# C270 webcam- no video--- audio works cheese, gucview, google hangouts, skype-- - the light turns on-- no images-black screen

Tags: 18.04, video, webcam

Ubuntu 18.04.2LTS
memory 6.8 Gib
processor Intel core i7 CPU 870@2.93GHzx8
Graphics AMD Caiscos
Gnome 3.28.2
OS type 64 bit
Disk 117.6GB

```
carol@HPE:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bda:0151 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Mass Storage Device (Multicard Reader)
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 413c:2110 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0461:4d22 Primax Electronics, Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 413c:1010 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:0825 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C270
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

carol@HPE:~$ lsmod | grep videodev
videodev              188416  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
media                  40960  2 videodev,uvcvideo
```